What is a reground component/part?
I recently came across this reground terminology for parts over here https://www.raxles.com/noregrind.aspx. This is a concept that is new to me. What is a reground part exactly? Is it just something that got machined a second time? How would you know whether a part you bought was reground or not? What parts are typically candidates for being reground?

I'm a little fuzzy on what this is referring to exactly. I'm imagining something like an engine being bored out larger could be an example of something being reground. In general it sounds like we're talking about some process that scales the geometry of the part either up or down depending on the application. Definitely material is being removed either way but whether the geometry is shrinking or enlarging is part dependent.
In the case with this CV axle stuff discussed in the linked page it would be shrinking. Regrounding almost reminds me of woodworking furniture restoration where surfaces get sanded down to remove dents and scratches to get down to smooth wood for a clean appearance and finish.

NO REGRIND At Raxles We Do Not Regrind
4 Good Reasons Not To Buy CV Driveaxles With Reground Components

It is virtually impossible to take used parts and hold them in
position for consistent regrinding. Inconsistent regrinding results in
an inferior product.
In order to clean up the wear on the internal
components, you must grind into the case hardening. Once you have
removed the hardening you have reduced the part's resistance to wear.
The part would be predisposed to failure.
CV driveaxles with reground components have been found to have excessively high failure rates.
Rebuilding with new quality components has been the only method found
to provide an acceptable, long-term solution.
Don't be misled by
unusually low priced driveaxles: it usually means an inferior product.
Your Raxles authorized driveaxle specialist using new components is
the solution for all of your CV problems!


